# ASP.net BeginInvoke not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, begininvoke

I'm sure this question will be a duplicate, but I can't get this piece of code to work properly, even after trying to change it in multiple ways following a few examples.
When I try to run this code I get an error of

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

upon trying to fire the `EndInvoke` in the callback function. Thing is, the program doesn't even go into `MyMethod`.

```
public partial class Ana_UI_CONTROLS_PrintReport : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public delegate DataTable 
      GetDataDelegate(string a, string b, string c, string d, DateTime date);

    public GetDataDelegate myDelegate;

    public void AsyncExport()
    {
        myDelegate = new GetDataDelegate(MyMethod);
        myDelegate.BeginInvoke(
          a, b, c, d, date, new AsyncCallback(LoadDataTableGridCallBack), null);
    }

    private DataTable MyMethod(string a, string b, string c, string d, DateTime date)
    {
        //do something
        return result;
    }

    private void LoadDataTableGridCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        AsyncResult aResult = (AsyncResult)result;
        GetDataDelegate myDelegate = (GetDataDelegate)aResult.AsyncDelegate;

        DataTable ris = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            ris = myDelegate.EndInvoke(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a normal console app or is it specific to asp.net?

Comment: Only in asp.net, placed in a console app it works properly

Comment: You can try to solve this but that won't be the end of your problems. See [this blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, hangfire sounds promising. I'll look into it